# Sitecore SXA search component in non-SXA page

Tags: sxa, sxa-storefront

I have my application migrated from sitecoreXP 8.1 to sitecore commerce 9 update 1.

Searchbox suggestion is working fine on storefront pages(which are SXA compatible).

I was able to successfully add the search-box to legacy pages(Eg:- career page).

But, search-box suggestion is not working on any of the legacy pages.

Any help for using SXA searchbox component on non-SXA pages will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the call to fetch suggestions triggered? Do your legacy pages include the sxa javascript? (can elaborate if this would be the right track)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is 2 step process,

1) Add "Default Commerce Page" Template to base template of the non-SXA pages.
[image]

2) Goto standard values --> Goto section Designing --> Select the **Page Design**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We faced same issue and we did the below steps and it started working.

1. Try to add the SXA template - "Default Commerce Page" Template

[image]
2. Go to your legacy page and add your custom page design